# Construction of measure on a sequence space

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

> Let $\Omega$ be a finite set and $(\Omega,d)$ be metric space with $d$ discrete metric.Let $(\Omega^{\infty},d^{\infty})$ be metric space where $\Omega^{\infty}$ is space of sequences taking values in $\Omega$ and $d^{\infty}$ is the discrete metric. What is the way to construct product measure or any other measure on this space?

I have heard that there is way using Caratheodory's extension theorem.Could someone explain me or give me a reference to read about construction of measures on the given space?

Comment: You need to give more information, otherwise the question is very vague. For instance, if $x \in \Omega^\infty$, then I can consider $\delta_x$, the Dirac measure at $x$. As you see, there are many possible measures, you have to give some further information allowing us to eliminate most of them and focus on what is of interest to you.

Comment: @AlexM. I don't know about Dirac measure.Do you have any reference to read about measures on arbitrary product spaces?

Comment: Measures on product spaces are in no way different from measure on any other abstract spaces, *unless* you also put a measure on $\Omega$ - which you do not do. If you decide to put a measure $P$ on $\Omega$ and want to construct the product measure $P^\infty$ on $\Omega^\infty$, then P *must* be a probability, otherwise your product measure will be either $\infty$ or $0$.

Comment: @AlexM: Sorry..why would it be zero or $ \infty$ if we dont put measure on $\Omega$ ?

Comment: That is not what I have said: it would be $0$ or $\infty$ if you put a measure on $\Omega$ that were not a probability.

Comment: I see..suppose $P$ is a measure on $\Omega$ which is not probability measure then why the product measure would be zero or $\infty$ ?

Comment: Because of how the infinite product of measure spaces is defined. If $A$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, then $A^\infty$, the infinite product $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega ^\infty$, is generated by the sets of the form $\prod _i X_i$ with only *finitely* many $X_i \ne \Omega$. This means that almost all of the $X_i$ are $\Omega$, so $P^\infty (\prod _i X_i) = \prod _i P(X_i)$ so, save for *finitely* many of the them, the factors are $P(\Omega)$. If $P(\Omega) > 1$, that product is $\infty$; if $0 \le P(\Omega) < 1$, that product is $0$.

Comment: @AlexM. Perfect! Is it true that any probability measure defined on $\Omega$ give rise to a measure on $\Omega ^{\infty}$ ?Sorry for silly questions and troubling you.I have just started learning about measure theory.

Comment: Yes, and that probability is even unique! Even more, if you consider the natural projection $p_{i_1, \dots, i_n}$ of $\prod _i X_i$ (endowed with the probability $\prod _i P_i$) onto some finite product $X_{i_1} \times \dots \times X_{i_n}$ (endowed with the probability $P_{i_1} \times \dots \times P_{i_n}$), then the pushforward through $p_{i_1, \dots, i_n}$ of $\prod _i P_i$ is exactly $P_{i_1} \times \dots \times P_{i_n}$. Notice that this works in general: the $X_i$ may be distinct from each other, and so may be the probabilities $P_i$, and the product may be arbitrary, not just countable.

Comment: @AlexM. So the uniqueness comes from Caratheodory extension theorem? Do you have any proper reference(notes/book/article) to read about this construction?Thank you.

Comment: Let me come back later to your question, I am a bit busy now.

Comment: @AlexM. Take your time,thanks a lot!